# How to provide passphrase for ssh key in docker compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:


  node-api-a:
    build:
      context: git@github.com:BasselTurky/bluekiwiapp-repo.git#main:api-image
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=MYKEY
    image: node_api_image
    container_name: nodeApiA-con
    network_mode: host
```

Every time I run `docker-compose up` it asks me for

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/blue/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Is there any way to include this passphrase in docker-compose, so I don't have to write it every time?

Comment: I don't think it's related to `docker-compose` itself, it's something you can configure in SSH I guess, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once.